# MYSQL ORDER BY clause is not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting, sql-order-by

I have table tasks:

```
id      title   date_task               complete

4948    Test 1  2017-11-10T11:00:00Z    1
4953    Test 2  2017-11-13T14:00:00Z    1
5028    Test 3  2017-11-21T11:00:00Z    1
5029    Test 4  2018-04-02T10:00:00Z    0
```

And I want sorting first: if tasks.comeplete = 0 order by ASC, others order by desc...

**My query:**

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    `tasks`
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN tasks.complete = 0 THEN tasks.date_task END ASC, tasks.date_task DESC
```

**My result:**

```
id      title   date_task               complete
5028    Test 3  2017-11-21T11:00:00Z    1
4953    Test 2  2017-11-13T14:00:00Z    1
4948    Test 1  2017-11-10T11:00:00Z    1
5029    Test 4  2018-04-02T10:00:00Z    0
```

**I want result:**

```
id  title   date_task   complete
5029    Test 4  2018-04-02T10:00:00Z    0
5028    Test 3  2017-11-21T11:00:00Z    1
4953    Test 2  2017-11-13T14:00:00Z    1
4948    Test 1  2017-11-10T11:00:00Z    1
```

SQL FIDDLE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f4a0/1

Thanks

Comment: You mean, if `complete` = 0, then the date should be in ascending and if 1 then descending right?

Comment: yes, because result seems Good to me, as 2018-04-02T10:00:00Z year is 2018

Comment: no, first sorting only if complete = 0, next others

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one way of doing it:

```
SELECT *
FROM `tasks`
ORDER BY tasks.complete,
         CASE 
            WHEN tasks.complete = 0 THEN DATEDIFF(tasks.date_task, '1900-01-01') 
            ELSE DATEDIFF('1900-01-01', tasks.date_task) 
         END
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/442081/1)

Comment: Thanks! But this query is long... :)

Answer (score 1):

It is fairly simple:

```
SELECT *
FROM tasks
ORDER BY
    tasks.complete,
    CASE WHEN tasks.complete = 0 THEN tasks.date_task END,
    CASE WHEN tasks.complete = 1 THEN tasks.date_task END DESC
```